# URL blocking with sessions

Tags: php, session

I have set sessions within my login system and it all works but not as I would expect. So by me manually altering the url and looking at home.php for example the user can go in without logging in but as soon as they click a link it boots them out. I am wondering is there a way to just automatically return them back to the index file if they have not logged in immediately. Here is my code:

```
<?
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
    if($_SESSION['user']==''){
     header("Location:index.php");
    }
else{

 include ('../../db_con.php');

 $sql=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE id=?");

}
?>
```

This file is included in the header of my admin panel. And I can see when clicking around the site the sessions are being created.

Here is my login code:

```
<?
session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']!='')
        {header("Location:home.php");}

    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=dashboardr;host=localhost', '******', '******');
    $email=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];

    if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM user_login WHERE username=?");
        $sql->execute(array($email));

    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
    }

        $site_salt="subinsblogsalt";
        $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

    if($p==$salted_hash){
        $_SESSION['user']=$id;

        header("Location:home.php");

    }else{
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we would need to see what the login code looks like to see what session vars are available, but blindly guessing, you probably want to do this instead:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}
```

(Remember to exit after calling header())

If that doesn't work, post your login code.

Comment: @coder123 don't use `$_SESSION['user']!=''` because that assumes that the variable exists, which it doesn't until someone logs in. Instead use `isset()`

Comment: How in my code would I make he changes, that is the only way I know?

Comment: @coder123 Just like in my example. Make the same change in your login page and anywhere else. just remove the `!`.

Comment: But the problem with the above is that if you alter the URL it just serves a blank page, can it not redirect back to the login page?

Comment: @coder123 you're talking about a 404 error now. Please hit the check mark by my answer and Google "htaccess redirect" and feel free to post another question if you need to. Good luck!